References for minimum distance estimator
What is the formula for finding the minimum distance estimator and how does it differ from GMM? Also, do you know of any good resources on MD? Can't find any besides my textbook. Thanks!

What is your textbook?

I cannot tell what the difference between minimum distance estimator (MDE) and GMM is, but there is some discussion of MDE and some further references in

chapters 8 and 9 of Hansen "Econometrics" (2022),
chapter 13 of Greene Econometric Analysis (8th edition) and
chapter 14 of Wooldridge "Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data" (2nd edition)


This is a handy pdf of the second suggestion of richard above. https://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~wgreene/Text/Edition8/PDF/M13_GREE1366_08_SE_C13.pdf
